# char* string to hex arrary in C

Tags: c++, c, char, hex

I have char * `para.mac`, string `c8934641d0b7` stored in it.

I want to convert it to hex array `int m[6]`,
make

```
m[0]=0xc8;
m[1]=0x93;
...
m[5]=0xb7;
```

I tried to do it with:

```
int i;
int m[6];
sscanf(para.mac, "%x%x%x%x%x%x", &m[0], &m[1], &m[2], &m[3], &m[4], &m[5]);

for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    printf("%i  \r\n",m[i]);
```

but it seems doesn't working.

and I don't know why the result shows to me like:

```
1178718391  
0  
0  
134448233  
8  
134272063
```

I think it should be

```
200(0xc8)
147(0x93)
70(0x46)
65(0x41)
208(0xd0)
183(0xb7)
```

so what's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track, if I'm not mistaken.

Consider trying: `"%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x"`, which means that each hex digit will only consume at most 2 characters.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the only %x in the `sscanf` function.

```
  sscanf(buf, "%x%x%x%x%x%x", &m[0], &m[1], &m[2], &m[3], &m[4], &m[5]);
```

Which will get only character of hexadecimal. But it should take two characters to convert it.
You can change the `sscanf` function like this:

```
 sscanf(buf, "%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x", &m[0], &m[1], &m[2], &m[3], &m[4], &m[5]);
```

Now as per your string : `c8934641d0b7`
The first %2x will get `c8` and the second %2x will get `93`, the third will get `46` fourth will get `41` fifth will get `d0` and finally fifth will get `b7`.

So it will work fine now.

Comment: note for OP: technically `m` should be `unsigned int m[6];` for this to work . Although on most systems the version with signed int will work anyway.