# hex arrary to char* string in C

Tags: c, char, hex

After got the answer from this question: [char* string to hex arrary in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29136615/char-string-to-hex-arrary-in-c)

I wrote a function:

```
u8 * mac_char_to_hex(char * mac){
    static u8 m[6]; 
    sscanf(mac, "%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x", (int *)&m[0], (int *)&m[1], (int *)&m[2], (int *)&m[3], (int *)&m[4], (int *)&m[5]);
    return m;
}
```

it working well, then I want to write a reverse function, look like:

```
char * mac_hex_to_char(u8 m[]) {
    static char * mac;
    sprintf((char *) mac, "%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x", (int *)&m[0], (int *)&m[1], (int *)&m[2], (int *)&m[3], (int *)&m[4], (int *)&m[5]);
    printf("---------%s-------\r\n",mac);
    return mac;
}
```

so what's the problem?

Comment: Use `%d` instead of `%2x`.

Comment: 1. What is that cast to `char *` doing there? 2. where does `mac` get a determinate value, because as-is this is invoking undefined behavior. 3. remove the ampersands  and the casts to `int*` from all those arguments; if cast at all it should be `(int)m[0]`, etc.. 4. Once you work that out, `%02x` may work out more to your liking. Lastly, I'm shocked the `sscanf` even worked, unless `u8` is the size of an `int`.

Comment: So what's the problem you see? Segfault? What line does it come from? What pointer values do you have in the pointers used in that line, when it segfaults? Could they be NULL or uninitialized?

Answer (score 1):

That's undefined behavior. Your variable `mac` is not initialized. Additionally you don't want to fiddle with a pointer. Use this instead:

```
char * mac_hex_to_char(u8 m[]){

    static char mac[6*2 + 1];
    sprintf(mac, "%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x", m[0], m[1], m[2], m[3], m[4], m[5]);
    return mac;
}
```

Comment: You can't read `int` from a `char` array though. This will give all manner of bugs related to out-of-bounds access, misalignment and so on. You _could_ do `(int)m[0]` however, which is as it happens equivalent to `m[0]` given default argument promotions.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I got the right function after read @harper answer. and do some modify:

```
char * mac_hex_to_char(u8 m[]){
    static char  mac[6*2+1];
    sprintf(mac, "%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x%2x", m[0], m[1], m[2], m[3],m[4], m[5]);
    return mac;
}
```

Comment: Careful. Your buffer still isn't big enough. You're dumping 12 chars + the terminator into a buffer only 12 chars wide. When `sprintf` writes the terminator you're invoking undefined behavior. Valgrind, btw, will eagerly point this out to you.

Comment: so I dont understand why the mac buffer not big enough, `m`  is a mac address in hex array.  `m[0]=0xc8` `m[1]=0x93`...`m[5]=0xb7` etc.  what I expect at the end, `mac` should stored `c8934641d0b7`.  do I have something wrong ? please tell me

Comment: You missed the space for the terminating zero. `strlen("abc")!=sizeof("abc")`. That's why you created *undefined behaviour*. It might work, it can fail. Usually it fails when it hurts most.

Comment: If your string will contain 12 chars, the target buffer needs to be *at least* 13 chars wide to accommodate the null char terminator. that's the bottom line.

Comment: I took the liberty of editing the answer to add room for the terminating 0 byte.